# Adding extension to Chrome mobile browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser

I, like must people use my cell phone a lot. I use the Chrome browser. But if I try to add an extension, say for example...a coupon extension... It won't add it to my mobile browser. Is that something that's possible to do?

Comment: Chrome for Android doesn't support browser extensions. You have to use other browsers as per the answers on the duplicate.